# Can I freeze chilli powder?

Tags: chili-peppers

I sometimes make Bulgoki where I use Kimchi powder - the Korean chilli powder Gochugaru.

However, I can only buy Gochugaru in one kilogram bags. Due to this, I can only get to use about one-third before the expiration date. Does anyone know if I can freeze the Gochugaru in individual portions?

Comment: I think the real question you want to ask is how much freezing it might extend the lifetime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I know to store my chili powder?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13041/what-should-i-know-to-store-my-chili-powder)

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason why you can't freeze it. Just try and expel as much air as possible from whatever container you're storing it in for maximum longevity.